# How to take the mod of high powers

Tags: number-theory

I have give $14862^{10000} + 405703^{555} \pmod 9 $
My idea was to separate it first
$14862^{10000}  \pmod 9 = x$ and
$405703^{555} \pmod 9 = y$. Then add $x$ and $y$ together.

I also know that $a^n \pmod k$ equals $(a \pmod k)^n \pmod k $

Of course im not allowed to use anything like a calculator or so. Could someone give me the result with all steps so i can look at this example and solve the over ones myself. Thanks!

Comment: By Euler's theorem for any $(a,9)=1$ we have $a^6\equiv 1 \pmod 9$

Answer (score 1):

Because $10^n \operatorname{mod} 9 = 1$ for a number the mod 9 is the sum of the integers. So  $14862 = 1+4+8+6+2=21 = 3 \operatorname{mod}9 $